# Sending udp packets using chrome.socket.udp

Tags: sockets, google-chrome-extension, udp

I was creating a chrome extension in which i am using [chrome.socket.udp](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_udp#method-send). I am following  [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network#connecting) but i don't see any data sent.

This is my code..

```
//var socketId;

var address = "127.0.0.1"; 
var port = 6454;

function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); 
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
  bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
 }
return bufView;
}

function sendPackets(){
console.log("sending packets");
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
 // The socket is created, now we can send some data
var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
console.log(socketId);
 chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, str2ab("hello"),
    '127.0.0.1', 1337, function(sendInfo) {
      console.log("packets sent");  
      console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
  });
});
}

document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', sendPackets);
```

this is the output i am getting in console...

```
sending packets background.js:16
165 background.js:20
```

And there is no sign of sent data ....plz help...

Comment: Sorry it's my fault .... for using the chrome.socket.udp you need to bind the socket...